# Screen scroll left and right horizontally in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have implemented Flat List (Horizontal) in React Native
scroll horizontal left and right, smoothly does not work.
I also tried wrapping up in different views but it's not working
and some error:Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"75325":{"module":"NativeAnimatedModule","method":"startAnimatingNode"},[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE4xr.png)

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const ProductView = ({ navigation }) => {

```
const apiData = useSelector((state) => state.ApiData.data)

const route = useRoute()
///-------------------------
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
const id = route.params?.id;
const item = apiData.find((i) => i.id === id)



useEffect(() => {
    if (item) {
        setCurrentIndex(apiData.indexOf(item));
    }
}, [item, apiData]);

const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const index = Math.round(contentOffset / SCREEN_WIDTH);
    setCurrentIndex(index);
};




// <-----------------------------------horizontal screen--------------------------------------------->
const renderItem = ({ item,index }) => (
    <View style={styles.body} key={index}>
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <View style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, paddingEnd: 50 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: item.image ? item.image : null }} style={styles.productImg} resizeMode='contain' />
                </View>
                <View style={{ paddingEnd: 50 }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 15, justifyContent: 'space-between', }}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>

                            <Text style={styles.textItem}>Brand name</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{item?.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity>
                                <Image source={require('../image/share.png')} style={styles.shareImg} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TouchableOpacity>
                                <Image source={require('../image/screenshot.png')} style={styles.shareImg} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                    

                  
                   
                       


                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>


        </ScrollView>
    </View>

);

return (


    <LinearGradient
        colors={['#7ABF49', '#13A15D']}
        start={{ x: 0.99, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        style={styles.linearGradient}
    >
        <HeaderItem navigation={navigation} />

        <FlatList
            data={apiData}
            horizontal={true}
            pagingEnabled={true}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            onScroll={handleScroll}
            scrollEventThrottle={25}
            contentOffset={{
                x: currentIndex * SCREEN_WIDTH,
                y: 0,
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        />


    </LinearGradient>
```

)}

Answer (score 0):

try setting your `ScrollView` to [horizontal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#horizontal)

here's a quick example

```
<ScrollView 
  horizontal
>
  <View
    style={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row'
    }}
  >
    {myItens.map((item, index) => (
      <View
        key={index}
        style={{
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width
        }}
      >
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ))}
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```